# Simplepie - A feed with an invalid mime type

Tags: simplepie

I get this error on host with simplepie 1.3.1:

```
A feed could not be found at http://pop-music.ir/feed. A feed with an invalid mime type may fall victim to this error, or SimplePie was unable to auto-discover it.. Use force_feed() if you are certain this URL is a real feed.
```

but on localhost(xampp) I can view rss

---

**UPDATED (2013/July/22 - 1:24 PM):**

I've uploaded full simplepie files.**[download My source codes](http://www.4shared.com/zip/HvwgrxJ8/simplepie.html)**

on this file, in `\simplepie\demo\1.php` , I set this code:

```
<?php
include_once('../autoloader.php');
include_once('../idn/idna_convert.class.php');

$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://pop-music.ir/feed');
$feed->force_feed(true);
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();
echo $feed->get_title();

?>
```

But in the run-time error is not displayed and not RSS is checked!

When I check url rss like this `http://pop-music.ir/feed` on my script, I get error bu when check this url in demo simplepie ([view demo this url](http://www.simplepie.org/demo/?feed=http://pop-music.ir/feed)) I can view rss!!!!
Help me :(

Comment: The feed `http://pop-music.ir/feed` appears to be valid. I get articles in the browser even though I don't know what the language is.

Comment: Also, it would help if you posted your PHP code...

Comment: I updated my problem.please check this.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Ty using `force_feed()` as suggested and see if it works. http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/force_feed

Comment: When I use `force_feed(true)` on my code, I get this error: `The data could not be converted to UTF-8. You MUST have either the iconv or mbstring extension installed. Upgrading to PHP 5.x (which includes iconv) is highly recommended.` Then I use `$feed->set_output_encoding('UTF-8');` and `header('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');` but not work! please help me:(

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Is it possible to upgrade to 5.x? Luckily the error message is pretty descriptive.

Comment: I use PHP 5.2.17. I explaning problem [in this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790167/simplepie-the-data-could-not-be-converted-to-utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

If this works on your localhost and not your live server then it could be that you have a different configuration setup or modules loaded. I know for me I just didn't have the `libphp-simplepie` module installed.

If you have ssh access to your host you can install it manually.

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install libphp-simplepie
```

*You will have to confirm the download by typing 'Y'
Then you will need to restart apache for the changes to take effect*

This was for an Ubuntu server if you have another server such as CentOS the process could be different. I just haven't tested it on another OS. This worked for me and maybe it will work for others.